# Get/Calculate Address

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, block, cryptography

I'm currently using a program that analyses the block files. It splits all the stuff into multiple .csv files. Is there any method I can do to get the addresses & amount sent/received from tx_in and tx_out?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what part is giving you problems? If your `tx_out.csv` already contains `value` and `address` and `tx-in.csv` already contains `hashPrevOut` (a `txid` value) and `indexPrevOut` (an `indexOut` value) - why is there a problem retrieving this? (apart from the huge inefficiency of CSV). IS the problem in parsing to CSV or in retrieving from CSV?

Comment: It's totally new for me. I want to get the address and value from tx_in.csv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why not use address in raw transaction instead of public key bytes](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103118/why-not-use-address-in-raw-transaction-instead-of-public-key-bytes)